# WP Job Manager Database Query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, plugins

I am just wondering if you guys know where the WP Job Manager plugin stores the categories for the listings in the database? What I want to achieve is to write an SQL query to select all listings (they are stored in wp_post) which are in a certain category and append some code into their fields. I would be fine writing the query myself although I cannot seem to find where does the plugin pulls the Category from. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved the problem and I'm just posting the query if someone would have the same problem.

```
UPDATE wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
SET p.post_content = CONCAT(p.post_content, '<div style="visibility:hidden; 
position:absolute;">hairdresser, hair, barber, salon</div>')
where t.term_id = 103
```

Note that this query is for a MySQL database and that you would have to check the categories term id in the wp_terms table if you would like to change something for all the listings in a specific category.